# Netlogo how to count turtles in same region

Tags: netlogo

I divided the netlogo gird into 4 sections and give region unique id. Turtles are placed randomly. Now i want to check whether two turtles are present in same section. If they do then separate them. I am stuck in how to write if condition that checks whether two turtles are in same region or not. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the things that you've already tried? If you share the code then someone would be able to help you.

Comment: Here is some information that will help you get started.  After that, you need to give it a try, and then follow joyson's advice if you get stuck.  The grid (the View) is divided into patches.  Each patch has an x and y coordinate called `pxcor` and `pycor`.  Each turtle also has coordinates, called `xcor` and `ycor`.  Figure out the range of patch coordinates that define your four regions.  Then `ask` your turtles to do a calculation that tells you which patch they're in.  Then check whether turtles are in the same patch.

Comment: is section a patch variable?

Comment: @JenB yes section is patch variable

Comment: @Marsi am facing problem in checking whether turtles are in the same section. i divide my grid into 4 sections. Section is the variable of patch. Now it is possible that turtles located at the different patches i.e. pxcor and pycor but in the same section. So i don't know how to check whether two turtles are in same section

Answer (score 2):

Turtles have direct access to the attributes of their patches.

```
;demo
patches-own [section]

to setup
  ca
  ask patches [set section one-of [0 1 2 3]]
  crt 200 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
end

to-report test [#t1 #t2]
  report ([section] of #t1 = [section] of #t2)
end
```

Comment: But if we have hundred or thousands of turtles in program then above code takes lot of time to execute (because it has to first make order pair to check whether they are on same section or not)

Comment: Please describe the problem better if this answer doesn't work for you. If you have thousands of turtles, how can you separate all pairs of turtles that are on the same patch unless you have more patches than turtles. You said you have four sections - so it appears you have no more than four turtles.